# Angular4 Change field B when field A has changed

Tags: angular

I have created a form containing two fields, Country Code and Dialing Code.

The form is used to fill a JSON file with key-value pairs, where countryCode is the key and the Dialing Code is the value.

I want to implement a UI where the Dialing Code is automatically filled in when an existing Country Code is entered.

How can I implement this in Angular 4?

---

Here is my Form View:

```
<label class="k-form-field">
    <span>Country Code <span class="k-required">*</span></span>
        <kendo-dropdownlist id="countryCode"
            formControlName="countryCode"
            [data]="countryCodeList"
            [textField]="key"
            [valueField]="value"
            class="width100">
        </kendo-dropdownlist>
        <span *ngIf="countryCode.touched && countryCode.invalid" class="help-block">
        <span *ngIf="countryCode.errors.required">Country Code is required.</span>
    </span>
</label>

<label class="k-form-field">
    <span>Dial Code <span class="k-required">*</span></span>
    <input id="dialCode"
        name="dialCode"
        formControlName="dialCode"
        [value] ="syncCountryCode"
        class="k-textbox width100" />
    <span *ngIf="dialCode.touched && dialCode.invalid" class="help-block">
        <span *ngIf="dialCode.errors.required">Dial Code is required.</span>
    </span>
</label>
```

Here is my Component:

```
public countryCodeList: Array<string>;
public syncCountryCode: string = "";

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.utilService.getCodes()
    .then((res: Array<PhoneCode>) => {
        this.countryCodeList = Object.keys(res); //--> Object.values(res);
    })
    .catch(res => { });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview

More specifically you likely want two way data binding on an input using NgModel `ngModel=[(someProperty)]`

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel